# Validating Kendo Numeric textbox to Accept max 15 digit min 1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

i have a kendo text box , which i want to validate to mobile number

```
  @(Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("MobileNo")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%;", placeholder = "Enter Mobile Number  ", required = "required",validationmessage = "Enter {0}", data_required_msg = "Enter Mobile Number" }))
```

Comment: Add a `RegularExpressionAttribute` to your property

Comment: Do you want to allow only numbers and anywhere between 6 and 15 characters?

Comment: yes i want to allow only number between 6 and 15 numbers

Comment: thanks i done it , and posting my answer

Comment: @(Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("MobileNo")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @max="999999999999999",@min="0",@type="number",@class = "form-control", style = "width:100%;", placeholder = "Enter Mobile Number  ", required = "required",validationmessage = "Enter {0}", data_required_msg = "Enter Mobile Number" }))

Comment: i can not post answer.. as i have less reputation so put it here in comment , kindly add the same code in Answer @Stephen

Comment: You can add your own answer if you want (just click the button at the bottom of the page. But your `min` and `max` html attributes wont work ( you could enter 32 and it would pass) and you wont get any server side validation which is most important. Besides, mobile numbers can have leading zeros so your property needs to be `string`, not a numeric type. I will add an answer bit later.

Comment: infact i want to add a mobile number which mean there maybe 15 digit or less , so 15 digit maybe any digit like 9254245242

Comment: But you have also said you want a minimum of 5 digits :)

Comment: That makes no sense because you also have a `required="required"` which means you need at least 1 character.

Comment: thank you @Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RegularExpressionAttribute` in conjunction with a `RequiredAttribute` on you property.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a mobile phone")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter between 1 and 15 numbers")]
public string MobileNo { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("MobileNo")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%;", placeholder = "Enter Mobile Number" }))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MobileNo)
```

Note that you should remove the `required`, `validationmessage` and `data_required_msg` attributes.

This will now give you both client side and (more importantly) server side validation.